# Structure or class which is better for linked list?

Tags: c++

For the implementation of linked list which is better

Using structure

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;
};
```

Using class

```
class ListNodeClass
   {
   private:
      ItemType Info;
      ListNodeClass * Next;
   public:

      ListNodeClass(const ItemType & Item, ListNodeClass * NextPtr = NULL):
         Info(Item), Next(NextPtr)
            {
            };
      void GetInfo(ItemType & TheInfo) const;
   friend class ListClass;   
   };

typedef ListNodeClass * ListNodePtr;
```

Or is their any better way for doing linked list in C++ ?

Comment: `For the implementation of linked list which is better` - Depends what you can use better. I do not see much difference.

Comment: `struct` and  `class` are functionally equivalent.

Comment: Unless you really need to implement one yourself, you could also give `std::list` or `std::forward_list` a shot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only one thing which `class` and `struct` makes differ in C++ is the default interface. if you write:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int a;
}
```

and:

```
class MyClass
{
    int a;
}
```

the only one difference is `a` field in both them. In `MyStruct` field `a` is public and in `MyClass` field `a` is private. Of course you can manipulate them using `public` and `private` keywords in structs and classes both.

If you are programming in C++ you should use classes.

Answer (score 4):

A linked list is one thing, its nodes are another thing. The nodes are part of the implementation of the list. They should not be visible in the interface of a list so their form doesn't really matter. I would do this

```
class List
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        Node* next;
    };
public:
    ...
};
```

Comment: @san45 These are matters of opinion of course, but in my view the important point is that the same author is writing `Node` and `List` therefore using friendship or getters and setters for the kind of fine grained control you are talking about is unnecessary.

Comment: can you point me a full linked list operations code in cpp because now im confused seeing different snippets everywhere ?